# How to make sure block-inline is working?

Tags: scroll, css

I'm having an CSS-problem on my hands which I just can't seem to figure out.

My goal is to achieve this:

There is a very big div (voyagescontainer), of 2190px width. Within that div, I have several smaller divs (voyages), which contains more divs (a fasecontainer with 4 fase-divs and underneath that an information-div, as wide as the fasecontainerdiv).

The problem I'm having is that the four fase-divs are not inline (although the CSS says "display: inline-block") but underneath each other when they are displayed outside the scope of the superparent div (which can scroll) I want them next to each other, but I can't seem to fix it. They appear nice and neath when they are placed inside the scope of the parentdiv.

To illustrate: I've made a JSfiddle with two voyages. One is immediately in sight (and works) and the second one is more to the right. As you can see, this one isn't neath at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/8BCur/1/

What do I miss?

**EDIT**

The point of the two voyages-divs being far apart from each other is because the voyagesdiv and the timelinediv are inherent to time. The start of the div is 1/1/2012 and the end is exactly 5years later, with 1day=4px. I retrieve the start date of a voyage from a database, and calculate the number of days between that date and 1/1/2012. That times 4 is the number of pixels the voyage-div needs to be left, relative to the voyageSdiv (which is 7304px wide).

Therefor, float and block will not work, because now they lost their position (which is the point of showing the voyage-divs ;) ).

Later on, when this is working, I'm making the div's resizable/draggable with jQuery so we can graphically plan stuff on the time-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using inline blocks, definitly if you want to be compatible with older versions of IE. In stead try using floats. Is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/8BCur/2/

All i did was change this:

```
.voyage{
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
}
```

to this:

```
.voyage{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width:auto;
}
```

You could add margins to make them appear further appart, not sure what you are after though...

**edit:**
Now that it is clear what you are after, i updated the fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/8BCur/7/
As suggested before i changed the inline style `left: ##px` to `margin-left: ##px`. Seems to work just fine imo. Note that i also changed the values into round numbers. I would advise you to convert the numbers to integers in your serverside script, as there is no such thing as half a pixel on your screen. Just produces useless bytes and you never know what our good friend IE might make of it.
Hope this helps, if not feel free to let me know!

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that is not the answer I'm looking for. See my update above for the reason why they are so far apart :)